# call webview javascript after facebook SSO

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I am developing an iOS app which display HTML contents with a webview, in conjunction with  facebook features implemented in two levels.

1. native app level - perform Single sign On (SSO) by ios native app facebook sdk (i.e. acquire access token)
2. UI content level - the acquired access token is passed to webview's javascript to handle UI display

**So my problem is** that after a successful SSO call is done, the subsequent call of javascript fails. 
To be more precise, when facebook app / safari returns to my app after SSO is done, my javascript is supposed to show a popup alert. However, when my app is returned (or resumed from background), the alert box is not shown, yet I can see it is trying to do the popup as screen went darker ( just like how before a normal alert box is displayed).

The app looks freezed up to this point, but when I try pressing the iphone home button and then go back to my app, the pop up alert is displayed.

I have built a facebookUtil class with singleton instance to handle all FB related activities, and the webView is actually initiated in another rootViewController class, and is passed into the facebookUtil instance.

**Inside RootViewController viewDidLoad method:**

```
   [[FacebookUtil instance] setWebView:(webView)];
```

**Inside FacebookUtil.h**

```
@interface FacebookUtil : NSObject<FBSessionDelegate,FBRequestDelegate>{  
    Facebook* _facebook;
    UIWebView *webView;

}
@property(readonly) Facebook *facebook;    
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
```

**Inside FacebookUtil.m**

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"fbDidLogin facebook.accessToken: %@",_facebook.accessToken);
    NSLog(@"fbDidLogin facebook.expirationDate: %@",_facebook.expirationDate);
    [defaults setObject:[_facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[_facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSString *jsFullString = @"javascript:myFacebookProtocol({\"access_token\":\"BAAGPxqGDC7cBAOAUaf0jtAEXXXXXXlAAAA5QZD\",\"action\":\"getWallPost\",\"facebookId\":\"SomeTestingPage\"})";
    NSLog(@"fbLoginAppActiveNotificationFired jsFullString hardcode-- %@",jsFullString);
       [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsFullString];

  //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsFullString]; });
     }
```

**Javascript function for getWallPost:**

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getWallPost(access_token,facebookId){
//document.write("Write after SSO");

alert("Alert after SSO");

    }
```

What I have tried and my guess:

1. It is able to run the javascript(i.e. alert is popped up) if it is NOT right after SSO. For example, I have a scenario where I run stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in request:didLoad method in facebookUtil, and the javascript alert box popup straight ahead.
2. It is able to display something on the page with document.write("Write after SSO") right after SSO.
3. I was thinking if this is related to the webview not being fully resumed(or ready) when the  app returns, or the webview (at fbDidLogin method) is not running in the main UI thread as it seems that the SSO mechanism done by FB SDK is done in a new thread.

I have been googling and looking at other posts in stackoverflow, but seems my scenario is not very common. I am running out of ideas now, and hope someone can share some light on this for me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for such scenario you need a custom listener such as NSNotification or Delegate, to call that once your javascript is ready to get invoked. Dispatch is also a good way of doing it, you can put your FB login logic in there in "Async", and once you get the response/request of FB, you can take that response and head to "Sync" to assign it to javascript. Hope this helps.